# Extracting a Specific Number from a String in Python

Tags: python

I have a string, which contains a specific number that I would like extracted into a single number.

```
string = Result: ResultSet({'(u'examplemeasure', None)': [{u'value': 15, u'time': u'2018-03-20T22:50:33.803894733Z'}]})
```

I would like the number 15 by itself as a result.

```
15 (<-- just like this)
```

My code is as follows.

```
import re
m = re.search('(\d+)', 'Result: ResultSet({'(u'examplemeasure', None)': [{u'value': 15, u'time': u'2018-03-20T22:50:33.803894733Z'}]})', re.IGNORECASE)
print (m.group(1))
```

However, the abundance of apostrophe's give a syntax error.

```
  File "filename.py", line 3
print (m.group(1))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to disregard the abundance of apostrophe's and get the number 15 by itself?

Thanks,
whyiamafool

Comment: You probably don't have a string, you have a `ResultSet` object from some library or other, which contains a dict which maps tuples to lists, or something like that. Just as you want to access a dict like `dct[key]` instead of calling `str(dct)` and parsing it with a regex to find the value for the key, you probably want to do the same here instead of parsing it as a string.

Comment: And if what's in there actually _is_ a string that was generated by calling `repr` on some Python object… well, who generated it? If it was your code, the solution is to keep the original object around instead of the string representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to extract a specific number out of a string with multiple numbers within a few minutes of OP.

You can remove the initial and last apostrophe marks from the string, as shown.

```
m = re.search('(\d+)', Result: ResultSet({'(u'examplemeasure', None)': [{u'value': 15, u'time': u'2018-03-20T22:50:33.803894733Z'}]}), re.IGNORECASE)
```

Replacing those apostrophe marks with quotation marks ("") around the string will solve the problem.

```
m = re.search('(\d+)', "Result: ResultSet({'(u'examplemeasure', None)': [{u'value': 15, u'time': u'2018-03-20T22:50:33.803894733Z'}]})", re.IGNORECASE)
```

The printed result of this program is...

```
15
```

(full code below)

```
import re
m = re.search('(\d+)', "Result: ResultSet({'(u'examplemeasure', None)': [{u'value': 15, u'time': u'2018-03-20T22:50:33.803894733Z'}]})", re.IGNORECASE)
print (m.group(1))

15
```

Answer (score 0):

The single quotation marks in your `ResultSet` needs to be escaped. Or wrap the `ResultSet` with double quotation marks.